# Django (DRF) trailing slash issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have problem with `PUT` request in DRF, and it is basically about the url not having trailing slash, but even  when i add a trailing slash to the required URL, it gives error (page not found 404) on the backend side, thus the data is not fetched in the frontend side
anyway if someone has any solution, please tell

here is my code:
urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include               
from rest_framework import routers                 
from main import views     

router = routers.DefaultRouter()   #Creating a router object which i assume is the web API root                
router.register(r'todos/', views.TodoView, 'todo')   #mapping views URL'S to the router (web api root)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls))     #including all views urls/route in the same url path (api/)         
]
```

if frontend side also matters:
app.js

```js
handleUpdate(item){
  if(item.id){
    axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${item.id}`)
    return

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding trailing slash in frontend side

```js
  axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${item.id}/`)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a param in the rest API router you can use to remote the trailing slashes:

```py
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter